# Как сделать чтобы в WebView работал выбор файла?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

Я только начинаю изучать разработку под Android 
Не судите строго)

```
package bla.bla.bla;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    private WebView webView;



    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);

        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://dropmefiles.com/");

    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать добавить слушатель для загрузки:

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Вот [ссылка-первоисточник](https://androidride.com/android-webview-example-tutorial-kotlin-java-download-source-code/#android%20webview%20download%20file%20example), так же [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069050/download-file-inside-webview) вопрос на enSO где вы сможете почерпнуть необходимую информацию.

### UPDATE

Для выгрузки файла [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907369/file-upload-in-webview) информация, нужно добавить такой функционал:

```
web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()  
    {  
           //The undocumented magic method override  
           //Eclipse will swear at you if you try to put @Override here  
        // For Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {  

            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;  
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);  
            i.setType("image/*");  
            MyWb.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);  

           }

        // For Android 3.0+
           public void openFileChooser( ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType ) {
           mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
           Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
           i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
           i.setType("*/*");
           MyWb.this.startActivityForResult(
           Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
           FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
           }

        //For Android 4.1
           public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
               mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;  
               Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
               i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);  
               i.setType("image/*");  
               MyWb.this.startActivityForResult( Intent.createChooser( i, "File Chooser" ), MyWb.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE );

           }

    });
```

Comment: К сожалению не работает, уже пробовал добавить в onCreate, это для скачивания, а мне нужно для отправки, кнопка прикрепить файл

Comment: webview показывает только веб страницу, если в разметке страницы нет кнопки то ее вы туда никак из активности не добавите

Comment: В том то и дело что кнопка есть)

Comment: @NULL, обновил ответ.